# In ionic framework how to set first ion-segment-button in active state by default?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic2

In `ionic2` how to set the first `ion-segment-button` in `ion-segment` to be in `active state`? I have tried to do it by providing the `active class` to the `ion-segment-button` like :

```
     <div padding>
        <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="home_tabs">
            <ion-segment-button class="segment-button segment-activated"  value="A">A
            </ion-segment-button>
            <ion-segment-button value="B">B
            </ion-segment-button>
        </ion-segment>
    </div>
```

But this didn't work. I want to make the first `ion-segment-button` to be inactive state and corresponding,

```
    <ion-list *ngSwitchWhen="'A'" ></ion-list>
```

to be in active state. How to do this?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This should be helpful: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#segment

Also, if you dont have a value for home_tabs at the beginning than the ion-segment component will not know what exactly you want. To solve this you can make home_tabs = 'A' by default on the constructor so the first button will always be active

This is in your component:

```
export class SegmentPage {
   constructor() {      
     this.pet = "puppies";
 }
}
```

This is in your html:

```
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="pet">
     <ion-segment-button value="puppies">
       Puppies
     </ion-segment-button>
     <ion-segment-button value="kittens">
       Kittens
     </ion-segment-button>
     <ion-segment-button value="ducklings">
       Ducklings
     </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
```

You can see ngModel is pet, and in the constructor it is setting pet to be "puppies" so the ion-segment component will make the button that has value 'puppies' the active ion-segment-button

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-preview-app/tree/master/app/pages/segments/basic

Comment: Thanks, let me look through this. :)

Comment: what is this `home_tabs` and value? I cant see any configuration says `home_tabs`. Where is that configuration is written in the documentation example? :(

Comment: In your code you are binding ngModel to some variable called home_tabs which exist in your component's class. Inside the constructor you should have: this.home_tabs = 'A' so the ion-segment component will get the value and make the appropriate ion-segment-button active. You dont need to add the segment-activated class manually

Comment: Yes, thats it, I missed that part completely. Many many thanks.

Comment: @DenkoMancheski The link at the bottom doesn't work anymore. Please update post.

Comment: Also, make sure. when you are showing segment at runtime base on the condition. then it necessary to add default condition is true when the constructor is called.

Comment: How to add the listener?

Comment: Struggled for 3 hours and found a simple answer, Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

The correct way to do it in the current version is like this:

In your component:

```
    export class SegmentPage {
        pet: string = "puppies";
        constructor() {}
    }
```

This will set `"puppies"` as the default active segment.

Answer (score 4):

Ionic 4:-
 We can write the value attribute of ion-segment-

```
<ion-segment (ionChange)="segmentChanged($event)" 
      value="javascript">
      <ion-segment-button value="python">
        <ion-label>Python</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="javascript">
        <ion-label>Javascript</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-segment value="all"  [scrollable]="true" (ionChange)="segmentChanged($event)" value="music">
  <ion-segment-button value="music">
    <ion-label>MUSIC</ion-label>
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="prayers">
    <ion-label>PRAYERS</ion-label>
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
```

just add the value attribute to the ion-segment. for example in the above code, "music" tab will be seelcted by default